# RapidMiner Cloud providing Rest API

Tags: rest, rapidminer

We have been exploring RapidMiner Cloud recently .We found that it internally uses AWS and can be used to run heavy processes.

Based on our learning, we could conclude that RapidMiner Cloud is really a rapid miner server running on cloud.

But we could not find ways to get REST API's and dashboard capabilities that locally hosted RapidMiner server provides.

If we use Rapid Miner Cloud, How can we get RestAPI capabilities.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

the RapidMiner Cloud is more an extension to run Studio processes on the cloud and not a complete RapidMiner Server with a RestAPI.

If you want to use a RestAPI you have to setup a complete RapidMiner Server instance, which could also be done on AWS or similar systems.

Best,

David

Comment: Is there are other product like RapidMinerCloud that provides this functionality

Comment: We need to host the rapid miner server on cloud. If not "RapidMiner Cloud", can you suggest what else can we look for...
I wonder why "RapidMiner Cloud" does not provide RestAPI capabilities as this itself uses AWS internally. Is this something which is technically not possible.

Comment: You could run a RapidMiner Server instance in the cloud, that is possible.

Comment: Pretty strange that "Rapid MinerCloud" which itself uses AWS internally does not provide API capabilities...
Now just to get that , users need to manually host it on AWS and do all the monitoring....